# R Dplyr Ifelse by Group

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

```
HAVE = data.frame(STUDENT   =c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4),            
SCORE   =c('PASS','MOD1','MOD2','MOD1','MOD2','MOD2','MOD1','ER','MOD2','ER'))          

WANT = data.frame(STUDENT   =c(1,2,3,4),
SCORE=c('PASS','MOD1','PASS','MOD2'))
```

For each STUDENT

- if any value of **SCORE** equals to PASS, then is PASS
- if contains value MOD1 and MOD2, then is PASS
- if contains value MOD1, then is MOD1
- if contains value MOD2, then is MOD2

I tried this:

```
    WANT = HAVE %>% group_by(STUDENT) %>%
ifelse(if_any(SCORE == 'PASS'), 'PASS', 
ifelse(SCORE == 'MOD1', 'MOD1', ifelse(SCORE == 'MOD2', 'MOD2', 'ER'))
```

and it is not correct

Comment: You are missing `mutate()`

Comment: `{dplyr}` + nested `ifelse()` is quite uncommon, have a look at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html (general vectorised ifelse).

Comment: you are mis-using `%>%` for two reasons: (1) the first argument passed to the first `ifelse` is a `data.frame`, which `ifelse` does not work well with; and (2) it is the WHOLE frame, not one group of it. When using `group_by`, the next function in the `%>%`-pipe _must_ be `dplyr`-savvy, generally from `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and a few other packages.

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)
HAVE %>%
  summarize(
    SCORE = case_when(
      "PASS" %in% SCORE || all(c("MOD1", "MOD2") %in% SCORE) ~ "PASS", 
      "MOD1" %in% SCORE ~ "MOD1",
      "MOD2" %in% SCORE ~ "MOD2",
      .default = "ER"),
    .by = STUDENT)
#   STUDENT SCORE
# 1       1  PASS
# 2       2  MOD1
# 3       3  PASS
# 4       4  MOD2
```

Notes:

- Your attempted use of `%>% ifelse(..)` is wrong for two reasons:

  1. `%>%` passes the frame as the first argument of `ifelse`, which is effectively `ifelse(HAVE, if_any(SCORE == 'PASS'), ...)`, which is wrong.
  2. It is the *whole* frame, not one of its groups. The use of `group_by(.)` adds an attribute to the following function, but that function must know what to do with a grouped frame. The list of functions that do this include `dplyr`, most of `tidyr` (and `purrr`, perhaps), and a handful of other packages. Notably, base R does not (and likely never will).
- `if_any(.)` is meant for column-selection, not as a synonym for `any(.)`, it's best (I think) to use `%in%` here.
- I'm using `.default = "ER"` here, and it works because the default value is a single-value (scalar); if instead the default would be (for instance) to pass through the first of the discovered values (in other words, something *dynamic*), then we would replace that expression with something like `TRUE ~ first(SCORE)`. While I know that isn't your logic, if you have a "default value" that is not a predefined scalar, then use the `TRUE ~ ...` method.

Comment: For the "if contains value MOD1 and MOD2, then is PASS" term, you I think you could use `"MOD1" %in% SCORE & "MOD2" %in% SCORE ~ "PASS",`?

Comment: Just add `all(c("MOD1", "MOD2") %in% SCORE) ~ "PASS",` to your cases.

Answer (score 1):

In base R you could write a helper function and use it within `aggregate`:

```
fn <- function(x){
    y <- c('PASS', 'MOD1', 'MOD2')
    z <- y %in% x
    if(sum(z) >= 2 | z[1]) 'PASS'   else y[z]
}
aggregate(SCORE~STUDENT, HAVE, fn)
  STUDENT SCORE
1       1  PASS
2       2  MOD1
3       3  PASS
4       4  MOD2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution going off of your original attempt

Using case_when is better here with @r2evans's solution but I still thought I'd fix it up using your ifelse's. Like others have said, you needed to add `mutate()` and also change the `if_any()` to just `any()`

```
RESULT <- HAVE %>% 
  group_by(STUDENT) %>%
  mutate(SCORE = ifelse(any(SCORE == 'PASS'), 'PASS', 
                        # Checks for any MOD1 and any MOD2 in the SCORE for that STUDENT
                        ifelse(any(SCORE == 'MOD1') & any(SCORE == 'MOD2'), 'PASS',
                               ifelse(any(SCORE == 'MOD1'), 'MOD1',
                                      ifelse(any(SCORE == 'MOD2'), 'MOD2', 'ER'))))) %>% 
  distinct()
  # Add in distinct() to get rid of duplicates
```

It's not pretty, but it makes sense if you prefer using nested ifelse's. Hope this helps!